# What are the similarities between quantum physics and buddism?

Tags: consciousness

What are the similarities between modern physics/quantum physics and Buddism?
Although i know little about this, like Budha said that conciousness creates everything, emptyness and dependent origination kind of things. What are other things that matches with what modern science is saying?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://philpapers.org/archive/CAPIOQ-2.PDF&ved=0ahUKEwj51PCXiY_TAhWWF8AKHW6nBcMQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNHCwMPZagzcHJxaJMnTe3u9czKmtQ&sig2=DvgBTQikkTmSZ6SDBVX5Jw is an interesting short philosophy paper to read.

Comment: This a quite a nice and free lecture on the subject https://www.freebuddhistaudio.com/audio/details?num=OM729

Comment: Maybe related: [Is it true that Physics confirms some of the Buddha's teachings?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/7386/254)

Comment: [This is the transcript](https://www.freebuddhistaudio.com/texts/othertexts/Jnanavaca/OM729_Buddhism_and_Quantum_Physics.pdf) of the lecture recommended by Crab Bucket, above. In summary: 1) things aren't what they seem; 2) the [Copenhagen interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation) may be correct or might be proven wrong; 3) everything is inter-connected -- but, quantum physics says nothing about ethics; nor about values (e.g. "why a human being is more valuable than a bacterium"); and views (from quantum physics) risk being reductionist, materialist, nihilist.

Comment: [quantum woo](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Quantum_woo).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know quantum physics does not teach four noble truths, dependent origination and consciousness. So there are no similarities.However quantum physics can be used as examples to explain Buddha's teaching.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9609002 , the relational interpretation is effectively in line with dependent origination and anatta.. sadly, like all QM interpretations, they are just that! Although it deals with the EPR paradox without any issues like Copenhagen or others, so people should come around to it, due to it being the most parsimonious one out there. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_quantum_mechanics)

Comment: what do you mean by "does not teach ... consciousness?"

Answer (score 1):

The Buddha, in aiming to comprehend suffering, from a psychological point of view, sought to understand experience as it actually is. The scientific method, aims to limit itself to the understanding of experience as it actually is, whilst not focusing solely on the psychological. Whilst the Buddha approached experience (mostly) from a generally more internal frame of reference, the scientific method approaches experience through examining the external frame of reference.

If the concept of 'Truth is one, the wise know it by different names' is accepted (one truth, rather than duality etc), then, subject to the validity of the Buddha's insight, the scientific method (an examination of experience, as it actually is), should agree.

Here the issue becomes the question of - which of the two methods has the more accurate insight? The Buddha taught anicca and anatta. The scientific method, has shown itself susceptible to anatta (anicca follows naturally from anatta) through the relativisation of physical concepts, as theories that embrace relativism tend to explain perceived experience better (statistically, mathematically), than ones with essential, absolutely and externally fixed constants.

[Interpretations of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics), gives many options for how to interpret experience as it is.

[Relational quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_quantum_mechanics) agrees with the Buddha's insight into anatta.

[Relational EPR](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0604064.pdf) is a scholarly discussion on how RQM deals with the EPR paradox (is quite insightful and not much maths in it at all for the most part!)

Answer (score 0):

**Quantum physics** deals with things that are a subset of

1. Rupa
2. Vedanä
3. Saññä
4. Sankhara
5. Viññana

And it tries to understand what happens to these in a subatomic level.

**Buddhism** deals with the understanding of Four Noble Truths of which the First Noble Truth is,

1. Rupa
2. Vedanä
3. Saññä
4. Sankhara
5. Viññana

And it tries to warn you that the assumption these things as "me", "mine" or "my soul" leads to suffering rebirth (hence Aging, Sickness, Death)

*While both seem to look at the same things, Quantum mechanics has a different objective from that of Buddhism. Thus, Quantum mechanics does not address the three questions clearly where as Buddhism does*

1. What is the pleasure of Pancha Upädänakkhanda ?
2. What is the danger of Pancha Upädänakkhanda?
3. What is the refuge from Pancha Upädänakkhanda?

Comment: "Pancha Upädänakkhanda" means "the five clinging-aggregates". See also [How does the first noble truth associate dukkha with each of the five skandhas?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/14498/254)

Answer (score -1):

In quantum physics states **every atom is impermanent**. Same is taught by Buddha.

Apart from that there is **quantum entanglement** which means if two atom or particles are entangled than it doesn't matter how far they are if you make any changes to one another changes automatically, **Buddhism teaches this in Mettā Meditation.**

Buddha was able to see every atom of his body was continuously coming to existence and dying at the same time, giving you the illusion that we are alive.

He told (10 to the power 21) times an atom is coming to existence every second, which is very similar to quantum physics.

The actual question should be about the difference, Which we need to understand is Panya (Pragya in Hindi, Maybe experiential knowledge in English) **When one find's the Quantum truth by Physics** one would still remain as same person, **but if one reaches to same truth by Mind, one become Buddha**.(Buddha is a person who has his Bodhi(Realization), Which means you will become self realized).

Comment: May I know any reference to what you have stated as "Buddha was able to see every atom of his body was continuously coming to existence and dying at the same time, giving you the illusion that we are alive.

He told (10 to the power 21) times an atom is coming to existence every second, which is very similar to quantum physics", please?

Comment: @AkilaHettiarachchi Yes Sir I attended 10 Days vipassana course in which we were told by Mr Goenka that Buddha was able to see how the mind is entangled with each atom(4 basic elements), the space with each atom is the 5th basic element and 5th element he said is mind which is entangled throughout the physical body.

Comment: @Rishi start reading the Tipitaka.

Comment: @RavindranathAkila Sir, I would request you to explain what is "Tipitaka" and Why one should read it?, What is its essence?, What kind of knowledge it has?, is it very interesting? or can I get its smaller version, Which just tells the truth in simple words.

Comment: @Rishi The [Tipitaka](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/) is the Pali canon; but the most important of these "three baskets" (for a lay person) are the suttas. For further details see [this answer](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/4111/254) and the several answers to [this question](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4112/254).

Comment: @Rishi Tipitaka is essentially the whole of Buddhism, and was written down in Sinhalese (Pali sutta etc written in Sinhalese) and later on given to all other countries. The original Buddhism (one that has no extra opinion mixed into it) can be read in easily understood inside the Tipitaka, in most cases. You will find clarity there, and can discard any false statements made by modern variants of Buddhism by reading it.