# Are the clinging aggregates the cause of clinging after death?

Tags: death, aggregates

There are five clinging aggregates. 
[Here](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/study/khandha.html#constructing_aggregates) it states that one's self clings to the five aggregates. To quote:

> "It's just as when a dog is tied by a leash to a post or stake: If it
>   walks, it walks right around that post or stake. If it stands, it
>   stands right next to that post or stake. If it sits, it sits right
>   next to that post or stake. If it lies down, it lies down right next
>   to that post or stake.
>
> "In the same way, an uninstructed run-of-the-mill person regards form
>   as: 'This is mine, this is my self, this is what I am.' He regards
>   feeling… perception… fabrications… consciousness as: 'This is mine,
>   this is my self, this is what I am.' If he walks, he walks right
>   around these five clinging-aggregates. If he stands, he stands right
>   next to these five clinging-aggregates. If he sits, he sits right next
>   to these five clinging-aggregates. If he lies down, he lies down right
>   next to these five clinging-aggregates. Thus one should reflect on
>   one's mind with every moment: 'For a long time has this mind been
>   defiled by passion, aversion, & delusion.' From the defilement of the
>   mind are beings defiled. From the purification of the mind are beings
>   purified.

It is clear that one clings to the five aggregates during his or her life time.
But after death the five aggregates dissolve.

My question is : are the clinging aggregates the cause of clinging after death? (Just as one clings to his own existence after death and takes rebirth)

Answer (score 1):

The last mind in previous life is **anantara-cause** of the after-life-mind.

The previous life, mind&mind factors&forms, is **pakatūpanissaya-cause** of the after-life.

The previous kamma is **nānakkhanikkakamma-cause** of the after-life.

The previous life is **ārammaṇa-cause** of the after-life.

**All above is clinging aggregate.**

Read: http://www.palikanon.com/english/sangaha/chapter_8.htm

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of the clinging aggregates on the link provided by you.

Comment: You asking for causes of rebirth aggregates. That link showing you  causes of rebirth aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the real nature of things is the cause of clinging after death.

Again: Ignorance is the cause of clinging after death.

Again: Not knowing the truth is the cause of clinging after death.

All three are the same: not knowing the real nature of things , ignorance and not knowing the truth.

All are not knowing ... ignorance ... not being able to discern lies from truths ... thinking "this is so and so" when it is not so and so ...

That being said, what was said is the cause of clinging after death.

Comment: You had said in an answer to previous question that " Without knowing the true nature of things, self cannot completely dissolve, thus it remains. This is key in understanding that after death some self remains and it does not completely dissolve."  This is not true... Self is made up of aggregates and at death it dissolves. In this [answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/14498/how-does-the-first-noble-truth-associate-dukkha-with-each-of-the-five-skandhas) it is said that "Birth is the arising of aggregates. Death is the disappearing of that which arose."

Comment: Then let me put it this way: The aggregates dissolve, but the doer who fabricated the fabricated aggregates remains.

Comment: Basic understanding is that self arises by the cooperation of the five aggregates. When one dies the five aggregates dissolve leaving no self at all!! But Upadana and Law of Karma exists...which again causes those five aggregates to reassemble. Your line of reasoning says when aggregates dissolve doer remains... If it is so then we have found an Absolute soul which doesn't dissolve on death of being!! Absence of absolute self is the basic tenet of Buddhism.

Comment: Let me see if I understand ... So rebirth occurs because of craving and clinging. Craving and clinging occurs because of ignorance (because true nature of things are not known). If doer at the time of death completely dissolves, then where does the ignorance come from to rebuild the self to cause his rebirth? Is it from upadana and karma because only upadana and karma remain?

Comment: yes. you understand it correctly. The questions you are asking can be asked in the forum. I can only say that Updana and Karma are inherent part of all beings and after dissolution of being, the upadana continues to exist and causes rebirth.

Comment: So, you're saying that from upadana and karma comes ignorance. From this it follows that if ignorance is removed, upadana and karma will remain. So, even though ignorance is removed, rebirth would happen because of upadana and karma remaining. But the Buddha said that once ignorance is removed, rebirth stops. So you're claiming that after ignorance is removed, rebirth still happens because of upadana and karma ... but Buddha is claiming that after ignorance is removed, rebirth stops.